# first page forgotten where to put the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code :

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

def forget_page1():
    widgets = [mLabel1, button]
    for widget in widgets:
        widget.place_forget ()

################################
mGui = Tk ()

mGui.geometry("600x600+545+170")
mGui.title("MyMathDictionary")

mLabel1 = Label (text = "Welcome to MyMathDictionary. Press Next to continue.",
                 fg = "blue",bg = "white")
mLabel1.place (x= 150,y = 200)

button = Button (text = "Next", command = forget_page1)
button.place(x = 275,y = 230)

mGui.mainloop()
```

If you understand my code .... there is a page with a welcome message and the user has o click "Next" to go on the next page.So on the next page i had to `place_forget ()`which i did . but wher do i put my code to put a new button or label on the new page where the previous widgets are forgotten???? i hope i was clear???

Comment: What is `widget.place_forget`?

Comment: weel is to forget the widgets of the first page and it works..

Comment: So all you want to do is hide the widgets?

Comment: no i alredy did hide the widgets of the welcome page but where do i code for widgets of second page???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you have just begun to develop user-interfaces. The storyboard is all events, in `Tk` you can set up custom signals and slots, but I think this simple implementation should work for now, all I am doing is calling a function to load new widgets, note I have not tested this.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

def forget_page1():
    widgets = [mLabel1, button]
    for widget in widgets:
        widget.place_forget ()
    loadNextPage()

def loadNextPage():
    mLabel2 = Label (text="Welcome to the next page.")
    mLabel2.place (x= 222,y = 200)
    button1 = Button (text = "Hello" )
    button1.place(x = 333,y = 230)

################################
mGui = Tk ()

mGui.geometry("600x600+545+170")
mGui.title("MyMathDictionary")

mLabel1 = Label (text = "Welcome to MyMathDictionary. Press Next to continue.",
                 fg = "blue",bg = "white")
mLabel1.place (x= 150,y = 200)

button = Button (text = "Next", command = forget_page1)
button.place(x = 275,y = 230)

mGui.mainloop()
```